# Both GET and POST on webapi with POST with a parameter but GET with no param

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, get, optional-parameters

I am trying a webapi which will support both GET and POST but the POST method needs to pass an alphanumeric parameter BUT GET should ignore any parameters.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("payment")]
        public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PaymentBase([FromBody] string hostOtp)
        {
            return await ((IApiPaymentController)this).Payment(hostOtp);
        }
```

I tried ,

- `PaymentBase([FromBody] string hostOtp)` and
- `PaymentBase([FromBody] string hostOtp="")`
- `PaymentBase(string hostOtp="")`

with this approach `PaymentBase(string hostOtp="")` GET works fine,but with POST hostOtp is never getting binded.

This is the postman code,

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:5094/api/payment/Payment",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "securitytoken": "0WnIxDep1knex1P13FmTWFKmIOBhgyc",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "123d6825-c723-732d-737c-1964dd8f271f"
  },
  "data": {
    "hostOtp": "eqweef"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

while firing from postman with `[FromBody] string hostOtp` getting error,

> "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'."

Comment: Why not have two separate methods for HttpGet and HttpPost?

Comment: If you need this `PaymentBase(string hostOtp="")` to work with POST method then you need to check my answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/35389449/797882

Comment: @FelixToo the GET is already in production for Mobile Apps,cannot touch that,new requirement needs to pass this parameter as well

Comment: please while downvoting let me know if I am in to wrong direction ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are Posting primitive type in the request body, you will need to wrap the string value in double quotes in your post

```
"data": '"eqweef"'
```

Or if the value coming from a variable

```
"data": '"' + hostOtp + '"'
```

Also, you need to explicitly declare that parameter is coming in the request body using `[FromBody]` and I see you did that.

```
[FromBody] string hostOtp
```