# Fetch, controller FromBody wrong

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Im Fetching to change my Record and the value `newInsert` is in the fetch true but in the Controller its false.

Fetch:

```js
fetch('api/Test/UpdateOrInsertType', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'newInsert': newInsert  //Console.log -> true
            })
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("UpdateOrInsertType")]
        public IActionResult UpdateOrInsertType([FromBody] bool newInsert) 
// Debugger newInsert -> false
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(Test.UpdateOrInsertType(newInsert));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Conflict(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What server side language is that because it sure is not typescript. And there is not react code in your examples. Your codebase may use react, but that has nothing to do with the issue you've posted. Please add the appropriate tags.

Comment: @AlexWayne Im using c# on the Server and I updated the tags.

Comment: I think that it seems that json stringify send "true" which doesn't recognize in c# `true != "true"` so you can change `bool newInsert to string newInsert` or if you just send one param value so why using `[FromBody]` .

Comment: I searched and also it may be because `[FromBody]` binding an object so you can try to use object viewmodel as param [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389191/webapi-2-frombody-parameter-not-getting-set)

Comment: @MinaShenouda ```String``` causes ```null``` and I need the ```[FromBody]``` because i refer 
several Objects. For readability I removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json doesn't work properly with primitive types. If you wont to use json.stringify you have to create a ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
public bool NewInsert {get; set;}
}
```

and action

```
[HttpPost("UpdateOrInsertType")]
public IActionResult UpdateOrInsertType([FromBody] ViewModel model) 
{
bool newInsert=model.NewInsert
```

or   you can remove { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

```
   fetch('api/Test/UpdateOrInsertType', {
   method: 'POST',
  body: { newInsert: newInsert } 
        })
```

and remove [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost("UpdateOrInsertType")]
 public IActionResult UpdateOrInsertType( bool newInsert)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should not use `JSON.stringify`.

Simply pass the raw javascript object to `fetch` `body`:

```
fetch('api/Test/UpdateOrInsertType', {
            method: 'POST',
            body:
            {
                newInsert: newInsert
            }
        });
```

Now on server side it will be recognized as a `bool` property.